# Pandas split column of lists in to row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like that.

```
   NAME      Age     shop_list
0  [A, B]     30      [AA,BB]
1  [C, D, E]  40     [CC,DD,EE]
2  [F, G,H]   33     [FF,GG,HH]
3  [I, J]     22     [II,JJ]
```

I want to split the name into different rows for the next step for merge to another table.
Just like that.

```
    NAME      Age     shop_list
0    A        30      [AA,BB]
1    B        30      [AA,BB]
2    C        40     [CC,DD,EE]
3    D        40     [CC,DD,EE]
4    E        40     [CC,DD,EE]
5    F        33     [FF,GG,HH]
6    G        33     [FF,GG,HH]
7    H        33     [FF,GG,HH]
8    I        22      [II,JJ]
9    J        2       [II,JJ]
```

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217968/pandas-split-list-in-column-into-multiple-rows

Comment: `df = df.explode('NAME')`

Comment: Please see: [How to unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)